# php / expression engine - redirect all URLs from one URL segment to another URL segment

Tags: php, .htaccess, codeigniter, redirect, expressionengine

I have an expression engine site that I recently redid and, while the titles of each article or page on the site did not change, the routes to them did. So, for example, where before I had:

site.com/site/code_single/name-of-page

I now have

site.com/main/code-item/name-of-page

How would I set up a redirect (either with expression engine tags or with PHP / .htaccess) so that all URLS matching site/code_single got redirected to their corresponding titles in site/main/code-item?

Comment: is code_single arbitrary? From your question it seems you only changed dash to underscore. Is that right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A single line of .htaccess really is the simplest solution here I think.

```
RedirectMatch ^/site/code_single/(.+)$ /main/code-item/$1 [L,R=301]
```

Answer (score 1):

if you need a php solution you could call this function before any other code is executed(at the top of your main index.php.

I use this to reroute codeigniter urls without keeping duplicate urls alive what would happen if you use the routes.php

For those wondering why? Google loves 301 redirects and hates double content. Codeigniter has a nifty feature to make your own "routes" so you can use your own url where you need it. The problem is, the original "unwanted/ugly" url still is accessible and if google finds this out, your page takes a nosedive in seo ranking.
Having found that out I tried to uncover any sort of 301 redirect function in codeigniter only to hit a brick wall everytime, and .htaccess redirects failed time over time(and i'm not the only one, stackoverflow is full with it)
So that is why I decided to write this, with keeping speed in mind so as little "fancy manipulation" as possible to get the job done.

You'll have to add these lines at the very top of your first index.php file of codeigniter

```
require ('myobjects_x.php');
redirecttoHTTPS();
```

I have called the below file myobjects_x.php and saved it in my base directory where the first index.php file of codeigniter is.

```
/* Codeigniter 301 reroute script written by Michael Dibbets
 * Copyright 2012 by Michael Dibbets
 * http://www.facebook.com/michael.dibbets - mdibbets[at]outlook.com
 * Licenced under the MIT license http://opensource.org/licenses/MIT
 */
    function redirectToHTTPS()
    {
        // remove this if you don't need to redirect everyone to https
    if($_SERVER['HTTPS']!=="on")
        {
        $redirect= "https://".$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'].$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
        header( "Status: 301 Moved Permanently" );
        header("Location: $redirect");
        exit(0);
        }
    // get the request url
    $uri = urldecode($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']);
    // check for unwanted trailing slashes.
    // if they exist redirect our visitor.
    // we want urls without trailing slashes so we don't need to to check the same url twice
    if($uri !== '/')
        {
        $slash = substr($uri, strlen($uri)-1, 1);
        if($slash === '/')
            {
            $uri = substr($uri, 0, strlen($uri)-1);
            $redirect= "https://".$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'].''.$uri;
            header( "Status: 301 Moved Permanently" );
            header("Location: $redirect");
            exit(0);        
            }
        }
    // if we have double slashes in our url for whatever reason replace them with single slashes        
    if(strpos($uri,'//') !== false)
        {
        $uri = str_replace('//','/',$uri);
        $redirect= "https://".$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'].''.$uri;
        header( "Status: 301 Moved Permanently" );
        header("Location: $redirect");
        exit(0);
        }
    $urilistcount = 0;
    //Just keep copy pasting this. In the orig you do the url without domain to check. 
    // The code checks the begin of the url, and if it matches it'll append anything that was 
    // behind the part you wanted to check. for example
    // $urilist[$urilistcount]['orig'] = '/pressrelease/82/something';
    // $urilist[$urilistcount]['good'] = 'http://www.domain.com/hereweare';
    // $urilistcount++;
    // will cause /pressrelease/82/something/we-have-something-to-say to reroute to
    // http://www.domain.com/hereweare/we-have-something-to-say
    // 
    // So make sure that your "top level" that's likely to match to a lot of sub pages
    // is placed last in the array, and that the sub pages you want different reroute urls for route first
    // When an route is encountered, processing stops at that point.

    // Copy paste from here and add below it
    $urilist[$urilistcount]['orig'] = '/pressrelease/82/something';
    $urilist[$urilistcount]['good'] = 'https://www.domain.com/media/pressrelease/31/somewhereinteresting-with-an-title-in-url-for-seo';
    $urilistcount++;
    // End copy and paste


    for($c=0;$c < $urilistcount;$c++)
        {
        if(strpos($uri,$urilist[$c]['orig'])===0)
            {
            $tmpx = strlen($urilist[$c]['orig']);
            $tmpy = strlen($urilist[$c]['good']);
            if($tmpx != $tmpy)
                {
                $tmpz = substr($uri,$tmpx);
                // special check to replace dashes to underscores

                // only when this word appears in the string to append.
                if(strpos($tmpz,'/iamadash-')===0)
                    {
                    $tmpz = str_replace('-','_',$tmpz);
                    }
                // add the extra variables to the good url.
                $urilist[$c]['good'] .= $tmpz;
                }
            header("Status: 301 Moved Permanently" );
            header("Location: " . $urilist[$c]['good']);
            exit(0);
            }
        }
    unset($urilist);
    }
// filter out bad urls character/strings that cause codeigniter to break
function CIsafeurl($string)
    {
    return str_replace(array('&amp;','&#8216;','&#8217; ','&','=','+','*','%','’',';','\'','!',',',':',' ','(',')','[',']','?','--','/'),array('-','','','-','','','','','','','','','','','-','','','','','','-','-'),$string); 
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks - think I found a good solution online that involves having EE dynamically generate a list of URLs for 301 redirect:

http://www.blue-dreamer.co.uk/blog/entry/expressionengine-301-redirects-made-easier/

Comment: I have tried .htaccess redirects, but they didn't work for me with the dynamic urls because everything got routed to index.php and it failed there.
If this method fails for you try my method.

It's just a matter of copy and pasting it into a file and including it in the main index.php file.
Then you just have to copy and paste the lines that contain the redirects.

That way you prevent any code execution before codeigniter tries to load up it's library, which results in faster 301 redirects.

Answer (score 0):

There's an add-on called Detour Pro that allows you to create 301 and 302 redirects within a simple admin panel in EE (it even provides metrics on each redirect you establish). It's worth a look if you have a lot of them to manage and want to avoid doing it in htaccess - particularly if not all of redirects have been mapped out and you need the client (within reason) to be able to create such redirects themselves.